# Getting whole post object with Facebook Graph API that we get with Facebook web hook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Following is the page post response I got on my endpoint that is registered with Facebook app as web hook

```
{entry=[{id=407976012733132, time=1451993872, changes=[{field=feed, value={item=post, verb=add, post_id=407976012733132_422139821316751, is_hidden=false, sender_id=192841237729683, message=Conversation started on 5th Jan 2016 by a user, sender_name=Naresh Pokuri}}]}], object=page}
```

But when I query the post information with Graph API(https://graph.facebook.com/407976012733132_422139821316751?access_token=) I got following response

```
{
   "created_time": "2016-01-05T11:37:52+0000",
   "message": "Conversation started on 5th Jan 2016 by a user",
   "id": "407976012733132_422139821316751"
}
```

But I want to know the `sender_id` and `sender_name` just like web hook response. Is there a way to get that information as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get those details with the help of fields parameter in query string as follows

https://graph.facebook.com/407976012733132_422139821316751?fields=from&access_token=

Then the response is

```
{
   "from": {
      "name": "Naresh Pokuri",
      "id": "192841237729683"
   },
   "id": "407976012733132_422139821316751"
}
```